# AG-Grid master detail grid de-select all from previously selected parent

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I have the below implementation of the AG-Grid master detail view. I also have selection enabled for the detail rows on which I'm performing action. My requirement is, that when we select any row from detail rows, the previously selected rows from all other parent rows should get de-selected.

I've tried below options:

```
detailCellRendererParamsForArb = {
    detailGridOptions: {
      columnDefs: [
      ...
      ],
suppressRowClickSelection: true,
      suppressContextMenu: false,
      getContextMenuItems: params => this.getContextMenuItemsForArbDetails(params),
      onSelectionChanged: params => this.onCptSelectionChanged(params),
      editType: 'fullRow',
      frameworkComponents: {
        datePicker: DateCellEditorComponent,
        btnCellRenderer: ButtonCellRenderer,
        currencyCellEditor: CurrencyCellEditorComponent
      },
      defaultColDef: {
        ...this.utillService.getDefaultColumnDef(),
        editable: true
      },
      onRowEditingStarted: event => this.onRowEditingStarted(event, true),
      onRowEditingStopped: event => this.onRowEditingStopped(event, true),
      onRowValueChanged: event => this.onArbRowEdited(event, true),
      onGridReady: params => this.onGridReady(params, true),
     },
     getDetailRowData: async params => {
      this.arbitrationId = params.data.id;
      await this.searchArbDetailFilter();
      params.successCallback(this.arbDetails);
    }
```

and on selection:

```
onCptSelectionChanged(event) {
    const selectedRows = event.api.getSelectedRows();
    if (selectedRows.length) {
      this.selectedArbCptList = selectedRows;
    } else {
      this.selectedArbCptList = [];
    }
  }
```

which is giving only last selected ids even if it still display selected for multiple parents as displayed in attached image:

[image]